# Measure space proof 2

Tags: real-analysis

Given a measure space $(X,M,\mu)$ and $E\in M$, define $\mu_E(A) = \mu(A\cap E)$ for $A\in M$. Then $\mu_E$ is a measure.

proof: Since $A,E\in M \Rightarrow A\cap E\in M$. So, if $\mu_E(A) = \mu(A\cap E)$ then $\mu_E(\emptyset) = \mu(\emptyset\cap \emptyset) = 0$. Now, lets define a sequence $\{E_i\}_{1}^{\infty}$ of disjoint sets of $M$. Then, $$\mu_E\Big(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_i\Big) =\mu\Big(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_i \cap \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_i\Big) = \mu\Big(\sum_{1}^{\infty}E_i \cap \sum_{1}^{\infty}E_i\Big) = \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu(E_i) \cap \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu(E_i) $$

I am a little confused here, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Read the definition more carefully. The set $E$ is fixed in advance and should appear in all the subsequent evaluation. Also, you are not "defining" a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathscr{M}$,

Comment: Summing is an operation on numbers. Intersection is an operation on sets. In your calculation, you are summing sets in the 3rd expression, and intersecting numbers in the 4th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in the calculus of the measure, for a  fixed $E\in M$ you associate 
$$
\mu_E(A)=\mu(E\cap A)
$$
it mean that the measure of each set is the measure of its trace in $E$.
So 
$$
\mu_E(\emptyset)=\mu(E\cap \emptyset)=\mu(\emptyset)=0
$$
and if you take $(E_i)_i$ a family of disjoint set of $M$ we have 
$$
\mu_E(\bigcup_{i}E_i)=\mu(E\cap(\bigcup_i E_i))=\mu(\bigcup_i(E\cap E_i))=\sum_i \mu(E\cap E_i)=\sum_i \mu_E(E_i)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Denote the disjoint sequence as $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ instead:

$$\mu_E\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\right)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\cap E\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i\cap E)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_E(A_i).$$